# Making nice, scalable rows using left-floated div tags of variable height

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-float

I want to display a series of  elements in nice, neat, table-ish rows. Each element will have a set width but will have a variable height (determined automatically by the content inside that element). Each `<div>` is assigned `float:left;` and `width:x;` where x is the same value for all such `<div>` elements. The result I am getting now is that if in a previous row of elements there is an element with a height taller than the following element, the div does not go all the way to the beginning of the next row. Here is what is happening (notice how Div 7 does not float all the way to the left).

[image]

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Notice how all the  elements wrap to make nice rows.

I could accomplish this with a table however I want the `<div>` elements to scale depending on the size of the browser (e.g. rows of 4 elements if the browser is wider or rows of 2 elements if it is narrower). Tables would prevent that. Selectively setting `clear:left;` would also not allow the scale described above.

I'm open to a JavaScript solution (jQuery preferred) or any other "hacks" that might give me nice rows.

Comment: Note: I just noticed there is an error in the way Div 4 would act (it would be under Div 2) . . . please ignore that even though if I diagrammed that part correctly it would demonstrate the same problem.

Comment: You might want to check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It does some pretty cool stuff (not sure exactly if it's what you want though).

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you just encapsulate each "row" with a div of it's own everything will just kind of fall into place. The row divs will grow to the height of the largest item ensuring the next row doesn't start before the previous one ends.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The problem with doing that (as far as I can tell) is that if the browser window is re-sized I will be stuck with a certain number of elements per row rather than allowing for everything to reflow to fit the page width.

Comment: If you want a variable number of elements per row then your description in the OP about being able to accomplish it with a table is not true. You should remove that for clarity.

Comment: He said 'Tables would prevent that'